# Select only first 2 records for each group

Tags: mysql, sql

My current result is given below for a particular memberid.

```
   MemberID    ResNumber    pcode   MemberEmail    arrivaldate
    601315522   33350554    CAAUBU  rjj@gmail.com   7/11/2018
    601315522   33350566    CAAUBU  rjj@gmail.com   7/11/2018
    601315522   33350574    CAAUBU  rjj@gmail.com   7/11/2018
    601315522   33354848    CAAUBU  rjj@gmail.com   7/11/2018
    601315522   33355136    CAAUBU  rjj@gmail.com   7/11/2018
    601315522   33356364    CAAUBU  rjj@gmail.com   7/11/2018
```

I want be able to select first 2 records for every MemberId, some MemberId would have 10 records and some may have 100 but i just want the first 2 records and reject the other ones.
That's the output i am expecting:

```
 MemberID      ResNumber    pcode   MemberEmail    arrivaldate
 601315522     33350554    CAAUBU   rjj@gmail.com   7/11/2018
 601315522     33350566    CAAUBU   rjj@gmail.com   7/11/2018
```

Comment: what mysql version you have? newer version you can use `row_number()` old version you need use user variables

Comment: How do you define the first two? What are you ordering by?

Comment: I would order it by arrival date, but these  reservations have the same arrival day and i want to be able to just select 2 ResNumber to give them rewards on a particular arrival date.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to do it with Row Number

```
SELECT MemberID, ResNumber, pcode, MemberEmail, arrivaldate,
FROM (
 SELECT MemberID, ResNumber, pcode, MemberEmail, arrivaldate,
    ROW_NUMBER () OVER w AS RN
  FROM sometable
  WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY MemberID ORDER BY ResNumber ASC)
) X
WHERE RN <= 2
```

Comment: @Sanky you marked this as correct, did you figure out what my typo was?

Comment: Yes i fixed the typo.

Comment: @sanky can you tell me what it is so I can fix it in my answer?

Comment: I just used (PARTITION BY MemberID ORDER BY ResNumber ASC) instead of W and it worked