# SQL to pull only the first 10 records of all fields in table, grouped by only 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, window-functions

My SQL skills are too weak to solve this problem, but I am pretty certain it is possible to solve.

To simplify - I have a small table with 5 columns, let's label them A, B, C, D, E. It's 1000 rows.

I need to be able to group by columns A and B where (E is not null and E <> ''). That part I can do.

```
select T.A, T.B, count(*) as countAll
from TABLE T
where not T.E is null and T.E <> ''
group by T.A, T.B
```

But then I need to be able to get just the first 10 rows of each group of all the columns ([A-E]) included in each grouping within those parameters. This is where I'm flailing. What I need to see is all the fields in the table returned for the first 10 records of each grouping.

The below seems very similar to what I need but I so far cannot get it to even compile on my end. I must not be using the PARTITION BY clause correctly (never used it before). https://stackoverflow.com/a/51527260/3536926

```
SELECT MemberID, ResNumber, pcode, MemberEmail, arrivaldate,
FROM (
 SELECT MemberID, ResNumber, pcode, MemberEmail, arrivaldate,
    ROW_NUMBER () OVER w AS RN
  FROM sometable
  WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY MemberID ORDER BY ResNumber ASC)
) X
WHERE RN <= 2
```

Maybe I should be using something besides GROUP BY like PARTITION BY but I'm not familiar with this?

Comment: what do you mean by "first 10" in each group?  what do you order on to know they are the "first 10"?

Comment: basically I have to be certain I am not retrieving more than the first 10 records of any grouping of employees and companies who have made valid submissions. Valid submissions are not null and not empty.

Comment: *cannot get it to even compile on my end*: what happens when you run your query? Please share the complete error message.

Comment: 'First' isn't a concept the database tables have.  You have to specify how you want the records order in the `over (partition by memberid, resnumber order by pcode, mmebermeail, arrivaldate)`  but you have to determine what comes first and is it decs or asc in the order by...and then where RN <=10 or as this is sql server you could just use cross apply and top 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is perhaps just a syntax error.  OVER clause is formatted like this:

```
SELECT MemberID, ResNumber, pcode, MemberEmail, arrivaldate
FROM (
 SELECT MemberID, ResNumber, pcode, MemberEmail, arrivaldate,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MemberID ORDER BY ResNumber ASC) AS RN
  FROM sometable
) X
WHERE RN <= 10
```

Comment: Yes. The answer OP linked in their question is for MySQL, but the outer `WINDOW` clause is not supported in SQL Server (even in recent versions).

Comment: By adding my where clause into the inner SELECT this appears to be working - I have to add some more robust test data but this is probably the correct solution- thank you!

Comment: 100% you nailed it - thank you Kurt!

Answer (score 1):

Is the order of each set of returned rows important?  This is a little janky but may get you close to what you're after.

```
WITH cte_Stuff
AS (
    SELECT t1.A, t1,B, t1.C, t1.D, t1.E, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RowId --Returns a random set unless the ORDER BY is specified
    FROM [TABLE] t1
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT t2.A, t2.B, COUNT(*) as countAll
        FROM [TABLE] t2
        WHERE ISNULL(t2.E, '') <> ''
        GROUP BY t2.A, t2.B
         ) x ON t1.A = t2.A
                AND t1.B = t2.B
)

SELECT c.A, c.B, c.C, c.D, c.E
FROM cte_Stuff c
WHERE c.RowId <= 10
```